# How to make a summ Method in Java

Tags: java, methods

recently my teacher showed us how to make a summ methode but i cant remember it.I think i got it a bit ritght.But it tells me error unexpected token a

```
void main(){
summ(6, 7);

 }


 int summ(a, b){
 a = int
 b = int
 return a+b }
```

Comment: You need to declare the types of parameters. Like `int a, int b`.

Comment: @Downvoters Please don't downvote a newbie question. Vote to close for "simple type", but don't additionally punish with downvotes.

Comment: Spend a little time in front of the compiler and you will get it

Comment: `a = int` doesn't really make sense - how can you assign a type to a variable?

Comment: @EJoshuaS There are languages that assert types using the `:` operator. It's all just arbitrary syntax. I could imagine a mental model where the OP's code compiles; it's not Java's (or any other language's I'm familiar with), but that doesn't mean it can't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
static int summ(int a, int b)
{ 
    return a+b;
}
```

Comment: Needs to be `static`. And the signature for `main` is off. And OP never prints the result.

Comment: ok thanks how can i print it now ?

Comment: @bot_diyar
You can use `System.out.print()` function to print the result